# Create MYSQL table with form values as column names using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I have following code that captures values from html form

```
if(isset($_POST['kk' ]) && isset($_POST['items'])) {

  $tablename = $_POST['kk'];
  $columns = $_POST['items'];

}
```

HTML form

```
  <input name = "kk" type="text" class = "form-control"  Placeholder = "table name">

  <input name = "items" Placeholder = "sql query" class = "form-control" type ="text" >
```

and then passes the values to this sql query to create a table with columns

```
$sql = "CREATE TABLE $tablename ( $columns )";
```

I type the sql code manually in the 'items' input form field like below

```
'id INT(6) ,firstname VARCHAR(20), lastname VARCHAR(20), PRIMARY KEY(id)'
```

Now, provided i have eliminated the 'items' form field and replaced it with 3 input form fields for example id,firstname and lastname.

Think about it in this format

```
 <input name = "id" type ="text" > -> id INT(6)

 <input name = "firstname" type ="text" > -> firstname VARCHAR(20)

 <input name = "lastname"  type ="text" > -> lastname VARCHAR(20)
```

How do i grab the values from the form fields above and pass them to sql query to act as column names(in otherwise substitute $columns variable that i was initially using) ?

Comment: I would suggest that you should design your form like how phpmyadmin allows to create a table structure

Comment: What string you are getting at last `echo $sql =..` ?

Comment: This sounds like code that is open to SQL vulnerabilities if you submit stuff through text fields and use them directly. Follow the advise of pravindot17 to use seperate fields for the column name, field type and specification, this helps you to properly escape the input

Comment: Thank you all.Seems a bit more complicated than i thought.I think i will resort to using php frameworks since they abstract the whole process of creating tables.